# Cross Platform Mobile Frameworks

Tags: android, ios, cordova, titanium, rhomobile

Can cross mobile platform frameworks such as Titanium, Rohmobile, PhoneGap ... support background services such as IntentService on Android and Background Execution on iOS? I am reading about Titanium but not 100% sure it support such native features on target devices.

Thanks

Comment: Xamarin has this feature https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/

Comment: Thanks, @Bhargav by any chance do you have any say about Titanium http://www.appcelerator.org/#titanium

Comment: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ! Titanium support background services on `iOS` and `Android`.

There is the official documentation :

- `iOS` : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Background_Services
- `Android` : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Services